# Site Collection second-level

Tags: 2013, powershell, site-collection, site, sub-site

I am using SharePoint 2013, is it possible to create a **Second-level site collection** by Powershell?
I mean, a Site Collection (not substite) child of another Site-Collection.

Comment: No, the model is `SPFarm` -> `SPWebApp` -> `SPSite` -> `SPWeb`. Where a `SPSite` always has a root `SPWeb` and `SPWebs` can contain children `SPWebs`.

Comment: Site collections can not be children of other site collections. You can make it look like a child URL-wise with managed paths or HNSC though :)

Comment: @RobertLindgren and is it possible to have more Site collections under a web app?

Comment: @NkSP Certainly, by using the two techniques in my previous comment

Comment: @RobertLindgren When I try to create a new site collection at the same web app url I get this error "Another site already exists at http://myURL."

Comment: Yupp, of course you do. That's why you need to first create a managed path for it, or use Host Named Site Collection as I have said before

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the managed paths as here described: [Define managed paths](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261845%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Just remember that you have a supported limit of 20 Managed Paths per web application (for Path Named Site Collections) and 20 Managed Paths per farm (for Host Named Site Collections)